# Unexpected Output Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
--Looking At Total Population vs Vaccinations

SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.population, dea.Date
    , vac.new_vaccinations
    , SUM(CAST(vac.new_vaccinations AS int)) OVER (Partition BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.Date) AS RollingPopVaccinated
FROM PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths dea
JOIN PortfolioProject..CovidVaccination vac
    ON dea.location = vac.location
    AND dea.Date = vac.Date
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL
```

OUTPUT:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 70
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, if you want assistance you need to provide more detail including a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `new_vaccinations` to `bigint` instead of regular `int`:

```sql
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.population, dea.Date, vac.new_vaccinations,
       SUM(CAST(vac.new_vaccinations AS bigint)) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location
           ORDER BY dea.location, dea.Date) AS RollingPopVaccinated
FROM PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths dea
INNER JOIN PortfolioProject..CovidVaccination vac
    ON dea.location = vac.location AND dea.Date = vac.Date
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: SUPER suggestion.... Thanks very much.. Well I will try and know the difference between int and bigint later...
It's been a great help though...